# Android Xamarin: If statement to check for "FakeProviderEnabled"

Tags: android, xamarin

So, my little app is setting up a fake location. This works, but there is a problem, it is this line of code:

```
        mLocationManager.RemoveTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
```

I have to remove the TestProvider, but I can only do that when there is a testprovider already enabled. And I cannot find a way to form an if statement. This is the best I could do.

```
    if (mLocationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider)) 
    {
        mLocationManager.RemoveTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider); 
    }
```

But no matter what, my app will ALWAYS go into the if statement. I think that is because I'm only asking for "isANYprovider enabled".

So how would I check for a fake provider already being set up?

THANKS :)

Comment: you have to specifically call AddTestProvider() so why can't you just keep track of this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do a `try`,`catch` around the `RemoveTestProvider`? It's not very elegant, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, you could use a boolean as well.